# Silence error: State-changing modifier on a view function

Tags: solidity, modifiers, view

In the past it was possible to use state-changing modifiers on view and pure functions. It was very useful when used properly because one could work out what the state *would be* and *will be* when the same modifier is applied to a state-changing function.

A little deeper dive on the idea of amortized work using the pattern: https://weka.medium.com/dividend-bearing-tokens-on-ethereum-42d01c710657

However, now it is more complicated to get the same effect.

This little contrived example shows the problem.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.14;

contract Modifiers {

    uint balance;
    uint refreshTime;
    uint rate = 2;
    uint PRECISION = 1e18;

    modifier accrueInterest {
        uint duration = block.timestamp - refreshTime;
        uint interest = duration * rate / PRECISION;
        balance += interest;
        refreshTime = block.timestamp;
        _;
    }

    constructor() {
        refreshTime = block.timestamp;
    }

    function balanceOf() public view accrueInterest returns (uint) {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

It's not happy:

```
from solidity:
TypeError: Function cannot be declared as view because this expression (potentially) modifies the state.
  --> Modifiers.sol:22:38:
   |
22 |     function balanceOf() public view accrueInterest returns (uint) {
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Is there a way to silence that error when impermanent state changes are the goal? One can silence underflow/overflow errors with an `ignore` block, so I'm wondering if there is a similar method for this case.

I'm aware that feasible work-arounds exist. Just wondering if there's a better way.

Thanks!